# How to implement default Roles on a Role Based Access Control

Tags: java, mysql, rbac

I'm implementing a Role Based Access Control system .

Users have Roles  (many-to-many)
Roles have Permissions (many-to-many)
Roles have Privileges (many-to-many)
A Role `belongs` to A Customer

I want to have 2 default **Role** s : *Admin* and *Normal*. The problem is , the **Role** s `belong` to Customers. So it means i need to define this default Roles for each Customer.

How can i avoid defining the same 2 Roles for each Customer ?

(The first idea i have come up with, was to keep the owners of these default Roles NULL , but this is gonna add a lot of extra control and forking over my authorization methods)

Comment: You can use the RBAC-With-Domain model in jCasbin: https://github.com/casbin/jcasbin

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I get it right, but the Role shouldn't depend on Users...

The general **solution at DB level** is employing a connection table, i.e. one USER table, one ROLE table and a USER_ROLE table with two foreign keys to USER and ROLE tables, respectively.

The solution **at JPA level** (I assume you use this because of the "Java" label you added) is to annotate the collection representing the association with a @ManyToMany tag and the framework will handle the rest of it.

Comment: ah no. im just implementing the mechanism, derived from Microsoft CRM. So anyone can create new User Roles for our entities and services.